# Animate a picture from left to right

Tags: image, jquery-animate

i am looking for a simple animation. I want to use "setTimeout" to move a picture from left to right. I wasn´t able to handle it. I did a animation but i don´t have a clue how to animate a picture from left to right.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Show us your HTML and jQuery so far and explain what you want it to be in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUNBT/)**

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#image1").animate({left: 1024}, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

> your image position should be **`absolute`**